# Why consider specific pmf when calculating expected value from cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, cumulative-distribution-functions

$$ F_i(x)= \begin{cases}
       0 &\quad x <-1\\
       \frac{1}{2i} &\quad x \in [-1,1)\\
       \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}(x-1) &\quad x \in [1,2]\\
       1 &\quad x>2 \\ 
     \end{cases}$$

Hello, I want to calculate the expected value of the corresponding random variable (X) of F2. The solution that was presented to me is:  $$ EX= -1 * P(X=-1)+ 1* P(X=1) + \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{2}x \,dx$$

Now, my question is why do we need to add P(X=1) and do we still need to consider it when  calculating the expected value of the random variable corresponding to F1 where there's no jump at 1?

Comment: In case $F_1$ we have $P(X=1)=0$. Then it can be left out, but it does not harm if we let it stand. This formula works for *every* positive integer $n$. That is handsome.

Answer (score 1):

When considering $F_1$

$$\mathbb{P}[X=1]=0$$

so nothing changes if you consider it or not.

---

Observe that, as $F_1$ is concerned, the drawing is the following

[image]

The mean is the areas with (+) minus the area with (-). Being the areas of the two rectangle identical, they cancel thus the mean is exactly the area of the triangle marked with (+).

Thus $E(X)=\frac{1}{4}$ without doing any calculation

---

Generalizing the formula for any random variable you get

$$\mathbb{E}[X_i]=-\frac{1}{2i}+\left(1-\frac{1}{2i}\right)+\frac{1}{4}$$

$i=1,2,3,...$

this is awesome too...

Comment: Oh, right, that's the case for any value on a continuous portion of the function. I didn't really think that one through. Either way what I'm confused about is why consider P(X=1) in the first place (when it comes to F2)

Comment: @ValidUsername $P(X=1)$ in $F_1$ is redundant. If you prefer  you can waste it. Nothing changes